# How to know if program is COM and can be browsed in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, com, objectbrowser

I am using VS2005 to develop VBScript tool, I want to use VS2005 Object Browser to browse all objects, I added cscript.exe and excel.exe, but I couldn't find any COMs else, when I tried to add notes.exe, it is said that is not a COM but a FILE!

How can I find all COMs in my Win7?

Comment: Project > Add Reference > COM tab lists all the installed 32-bit servers on your machine.  This isn't exactly a guarantee that you'll know how to use such a server however, very unclear what this tool is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CScript and Wscript are starter programs. The COM objects reside in C:\Windows\System32\wshom.ocx

The wscript base object is only available to scripts it is running, other sub objects do the following.

Look up in `Regedit` - `HKCR\wscript.shell` (the object name) - look up the CLSID under this key at `HKCR\CLSID\<the GUID>` and look under `InProcServer32` for DLLs (and OCXs are DLLs with a funny extension) and EXE under `LocalServer32`.